# SQL Oracle - Excel's BETAINV function (Inverse cumulative function of a beta distribution) in SQL Oracle

Tags: distribution, sql

Is there a function equal to Excel's **BETAINV(probability,alpha,beta,[A],[B])** in Oracle SQL Developer? Or a similar one which I could use to return the inverse cumulative distribution function of a beta distribution?